# Get mean value from dnorm

Tags: r, normal-distribution

In the following code I am trying to get the mean value from normal1 and normal2 so that I don't have to hard code in the `xintercept` values (3 and 0) in the `geom_vline` function call.

```
normal1 <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, 3, 3)
}

normal2 <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, 0, 2)
}

plot + stat_function(fun = normal1) +
       stat_function(fun = normal2) + xlim(c(-10, 15)) +
       geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed") +
       geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")
```

I'd like to do so without forward declaring the variable and using them in the initial `dnorm` call. ie

```
x1 <- 3
x2 <- 0

normal1 <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, x1, 3)
}

normal2 <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, x2, 2)
}
```

I am very new to R, and don't have a strong grasp of functions or returns in it.

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example of what `plot` is?

Comment: Oh, thank you, your comment made me realize that the `plot` I was using was a variable in the console's memory that I had since deleted from the code.  `plot <- ggplot(x, aes(x))`

Comment: Thank. In the mean time, there's an answer, and a good one, I've upvoted it after a test. Maybe you should accept it, so that others can find it in the future if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you try something like this

```
plotter <- function(m1,m2){
  normal1 <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, m1, 3)
  }

  normal2 <- function(x) {
    dnorm(x, m2, 2)
  }
  ggplot(data = data.frame(x=0), mapping = aes(x=x))+ 
  stat_function(fun = normal1) +
    stat_function(fun = normal2) + xlim(-10, 15) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = m1, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = m2, linetype = "dashed")


}
```

So you can re-calculate the normal1 and normal2 function. In fact they are created with a variable mean, it is easy to modify the plot with new values.

```
m_1 <- 4
m_2 <- 2

plotter(m_1, m_2)
```

or execute the plotter() function directly with new values.

---

Excursion

In fact, calculating the mean of a function which necessarily needs the mean for its creation is a bit confusing, but not impossible.

First modify the `plotter` function a bit:

```
normal1 <<- function(x) {
  dnorm(x, m1, 3)
}
```

so the `normal1` function is available outside the `plotter` function.

Now we have a look on the mathematical background: the mean or the expected value of a function coincides with the area under the curve of the density multiplied with the variable itself.

```
mean1 <- function(x){
normal1(x)*x
}
```

where `normal1` is interpreted as the density.

```
mean1_empirical <- integrate(mean1, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)
```

For `m_1 <- 4` the result is, for example **(!)**:

```
4 with absolute error < 0.00019
```

Please note: using this method with an existing function is an **empirical approach**. So it is possible to receive results with minimal derivation but of course a high accuracy.

Comment: That is cleaner than the way I was doing it, and it works well for this instance, but I was hoping for a way to actually extract the mean after the fact.  So if I am passed a naked plot I would be able to add the `geom_vline` to it.

Comment: @Kebtiz, hope I could help a bit with the excursion